# How to change record type by workflow?

Tags: workflow, record-type, field-update

"By changing the pick list field value, trigger the workflow to change the record type id  accordingly " how can we achieve this.
 please help

Comment: Updating the RecordType with Workflow should be straight-forward, what problem are you having?

Comment: Hi I've put in a step by step instrcution for you, however, please note that you should familiarise yourself with the Salesforce Help documentation available when you log into your Salesforce.com production organisation. Also, please note that you should use best practices when configuring the org, e.g., where possible build ad test in sandbox and then deploy via changeset to the production org.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for simple steps on how to do this for the first time:

1. Go to Setup | Create | Workflow & Approvals | Workflow Rules | New.
2. Then select the object you want to run the workflow on, e.g., opp'y.
3. Click Next, give it a name, set your evaluation criteria and select the criteria that the rule should fire under, e.g., when picklist value is "itemA".
4. Click "Save & Next", select a Workflow action "New Field update", give it a name and select the object "opportunity" and the field you want to update, e.g., "opportunity record type",
5. Select the record type form list list presented.
6. Click Save. Don't forget to go back to the rule and activate it (edit and select activate).

If you are faced with a challenge outside of this please edit your question.