# Trying to create a validation rule to stop the user (a mechanic) from updating or editing a repair record once the record has been marked completed

Tags: formula, validation-rule

The Mechanic will fill out a repair record and can mark it as 'Not Started', 'In Progress, and 'Completed'. Once they mark the repair record as completed they should not be able to edit any of the fields on the report. 
This is what I have so far but it does not seem to be working.
I have tried some other things as well but I am stuck.

```
AND( 
   TEXT(PRIORVALUE( Status__c )) = "Completed",
   ISCHANGED( Status__c ),
    ISCHANGED( Actual_Cost__c ),
   ISCHANGED( Actual_Hours__c  ),
   ISCHANGED(  Calculated_Cost__c  ),
   ISCHANGED( Car__c  ),
   ISCHANGED(  Cost_Per_Hour__c  ),
  ISCHANGED(  Date_Completed__c  ),
  ISCHANGED(  Estimated_Cost__c  ),
  ISCHANGED(  Estimated_Hours__c  ),
  ISCHANGED(  Mechanic__c ),
  ISCHANGED(  Mechanic_Comments__c ),
  ISCHANGED(  Reason_for_Service__c  ),
  ISCHANGED( Name ),
   $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this simple validation rule:

my bad, I updated the sol

```
AND (
    NOT(ISNEW()),
    IF (ISCHANGED(Status__c), 
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),'Completed'),
        ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Completed')
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this response! I tried it but It is still letting me change the fields on the record.

Comment: @Danielle, I just updated the formula.

Comment: Thanks!! This worked

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to this question but a suggestion for an alternative approach:

1. Set up record types for your repair record object
2. Add a process builder to set the record type based on your picklist values (see this example [How to change record type by workflow?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51092/how-to-change-record-type-by-workflow))
3. Add record type based permissions to your user profiles)